# iOS8 Safari after a pushState the :nth-child() selectors not works

Tags: javascript, css, safari, ios8, css-selectors

Edited:
I reported this bug to Apple and now its closed, tested on beta iOS 9.0 (13A4254v) and works correctly.

Edited for better explanation:

I have a bunch of articles in a web page, all wrapped into a div (column). These articles have a class with absolute position, and fixed width and height.

there is a button to apply:
- a translate3d to the wrapper/column
- a window.history.pushState

All the styles are applied correctly to all the articles, but when i push the button and after the pushState, all/some of the nth-child() styles are not applied correctly (left, top and width). If i change the :nth-child() to :nth-of-type() all works correctly after the pushState.

The problem seems to be visible when safari determines to activate the possibility to switch into reader mode, after pushing the click button and affects to the translate3d elements (hardware accelerated).

It happends on Safari iOS8 using iPad2, iPad3 retina and 4. it don't happends using an iPad mini retina. Using iOS7 and before all works correctly, but no works using iOS8.

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale = 1.0, minimum-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = 1.0">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <style>
        body {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        #column {
            -webkit-transition: 0.35s; transition: 0.35s;
            -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);

            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            left: 10px;

            border: 1px solid Grey;
            width: 300px;
            height: 225px;
        }
        .moveColumn {
            -webkit-transform: translate3d(200px, 0px, 0px) !important;
        }

    article {
        position: absolute;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    article:nth-child(1) {
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        background-color: Red;
    }
    article:nth-child(2) {
        left: 0px;
        top: 305px;
        width: 605px;
        height: 300px;
        background-color: Blue;
    }
    article:nth-child(3) {
        left: 305px;
        top: 0;
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        background-color: Green;
    }
    .button {
        position: absolute;
        left: 10px;
        top: 250px;
        background-color: Grey;
    }

    </style>
    <script language="javascript">
        var veces = 0;
        function moveColumn() {
            var column = document.querySelector('#column');

            column.classList.toggle('moveColumn');

            var obj = {};
            obj.sectionId = "section";
            window.history.pushState(obj, "TITLE", "/?vp=" + veces);
            veces++;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="column">
        <article>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eu urna quam. Duis et pellentesque ipsum, vitae varius erat. Nullam fringilla libero id est aliquet gravida. Quisque efficitur, quam bibendum posuere auctor, turpis arcu pulvinar sapien, interdum iaculis purus metus id velit. In in lorem ac dolor feugiat luctus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi viverra velit sed massa viverra consequat id eu tortor. Ut scelerisque massa ut leo rutrum blandit.

            Maecenas sit amet facilisis nulla, nec convallis nunc. Ut gravida, erat eget eleifend viverra, elit lacus ultrices turpis, vitae molestie felis tellus ac eros. Integer semper vitae sapien sit amet placerat. Praesent in sodales massa. Aliquam erat volutpat. Etiam maximus massa a scelerisque cursus. Pellentesque facilisis enim nec diam viverra facilisis. Morbi non nibh nulla. Praesent erat urna, porta sit amet dui eu, porta pulvinar metus. Nam quam odio, laoreet in nisi in, porta efficitur purus. In fringilla magna ac accumsan commodo.</article>
        <article>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eu urna quam. Duis et pellentesque ipsum, vitae varius erat. Nullam fringilla libero id est aliquet gravida. Quisque efficitur, quam bibendum posuere auctor, turpis arcu pulvinar sapien, interdum iaculis purus metus id velit. In in lorem ac dolor feugiat luctus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi viverra velit sed massa viverra consequat id eu tortor. Ut scelerisque massa ut leo rutrum blandit.

            Maecenas sit amet facilisis nulla, nec convallis nunc. Ut gravida, erat eget eleifend viverra, elit lacus ultrices turpis, vitae molestie felis tellus ac eros. Integer semper vitae sapien sit amet placerat. Praesent in sodales massa. Aliquam erat volutpat. Etiam maximus massa a scelerisque cursus. Pellentesque facilisis enim nec diam viverra facilisis. Morbi non nibh nulla. Praesent erat urna, porta sit amet dui eu, porta pulvinar metus. Nam quam odio, laoreet in nisi in, porta efficitur purus. In fringilla magna ac accumsan commodo.</article>
        <article>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eu urna quam. Duis et pellentesque ipsum, vitae varius erat. Nullam fringilla libero id est aliquet gravida. Quisque efficitur, quam bibendum posuere auctor, turpis arcu pulvinar sapien, interdum iaculis purus metus id velit. In in lorem ac dolor feugiat luctus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi viverra velit sed massa viverra consequat id eu tortor. Ut scelerisque massa ut leo rutrum blandit.

            Maecenas sit amet facilisis nulla, nec convallis nunc. Ut gravida, erat eget eleifend viverra, elit lacus ultrices turpis, vitae molestie felis tellus ac eros. Integer semper vitae sapien sit amet placerat. Praesent in sodales massa. Aliquam erat volutpat. Etiam maximus massa a scelerisque cursus. Pellentesque facilisis enim nec diam viverra facilisis. Morbi non nibh nulla. Praesent erat urna, porta sit amet dui eu, porta pulvinar metus. Nam quam odio, laoreet in nisi in, porta efficitur purus. In fringilla magna ac accumsan commodo.</article>
    </div>

    <div class="button" onclick="javascript:moveColumn();"> Click me to move column</div>
</body>
</html>
```

have you experienced something like that?

Comment: The problem seems to be visible when safari determines to activate the possibility to switch into reader mode. I can reproduce the problem on a simple HTML page with the same code listed, but including a few text into articles to let safari to activate the reader mode button.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Indeed `nth-child` doesn't work on IOS8.

Switching for `nth-of-type` did the trick for me.

It's well supported https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type

That said if you want to take no chance, you can detect IOS 8 as follow.

```
function isIOS8() {
  if ("600.1.4" == $.browser.version || ~navigator.userAgent.indexOf('OS 8_') ){
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

var i=0,
    $el = $('ul.poll');

if( isIOS8() ){
    $el.find(' li:nth-of-type(' + (i + 1) + ')').text('my first Child');
}else{
    $el.find('.choice:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')').text('my first Child');
}
```

Comment: Thats the solution i adopted with the inconvenient that semantic meaning of :nth-of-type() its different than :nth-child(). I registered that bug to apple. Thanks.

Comment: I agree that it's less separation of concerns. Having to use tagname in selectors is neither ideal to me. Thanks for reporting that bug.

Comment: Hey @josea do you have a link for that bug report?

Comment: Could just be me but it looks like iOS 8.1.2 update fixes this issue?

Comment: @Cub3 sorry but no, i am able to reproduce it on ipad mini ios8.1.2

Comment: I'm using iOS 8.1.2 and it seems to be working for me.

Comment: I got response from apple, to test it with ios9.0 beta and it works for me using 9.0 (13A4254v). The apple bug is now closed.

Answer (score 3):

When appending new elements to list (e.g. with AJAX) `:nth-child(2n+1)` appears applied to every new element.

This happens only on 32-bit devices running iOS8 (e.g. iPhone5 but not iPhone 5s or 6 and even not iPhone5 Simulator).

The solution is to use `:nth-of-type()` until Apple addresses this issue.

Answer (score 3):

I have encountered a similar issue and I'm adding it here in case others come looking as this is the only post I have found regarding iOS 8 and CSS selector problems.

My particular problem is using nth-child to select elements created by Javascript, and we make good use of nth-child, which is no longer working on iOS 8.

`nth-of-type` *does* work, as svassr states in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26128731/4012426).

I have created a [js sample](http://jsfiddle.net/2foxhmvs/1/) (also code at end) that shows the problem with iOS 8 and document.querySelectAll in conjunction with the nth-child css selector.

Speculating from info [here](http://kendsnyder.com/apple-shows-love-for-html5-with-ios-8/), and the quote below in particular, I think they're caching or pre-processing the selectors.

> iOS 8 is also significantly faster than iOS7 in every area with a 4x improvement in document.querySelectorAll.

```
<style>
    .red { border: 1px solid red; }

    .green { border: 1px solid green; }

    tr.test > td:nth-child(n) { background-color: yellow; }
</style>

<table id='tbl'>
    <tr>
        <td>a1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='test'>
        <td>b1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='test'>
        <td>c1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>d1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='test'>
        <td>e1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
var row = $('<tr></tr>').addClass('test');

var cell1 = $('<td></td>').text('f1');
cell1.appendTo(row);

var cell2 = $('<td></td>').text('2');
cell2.appendTo(row);

var cell3 = $('<td></td>').text('3');
cell3.appendTo(row);

var cell4 = $('<td></td>').text('4');
cell4.appendTo(row);

var cell5 = $('<td></td>').text('5');
cell5.appendTo(row);

var tbl = $('#tbl');
row.appendTo(tbl);

var iRedCol = 3;
$('#tbl').find('tr.test > td:nth-child(' + iRedCol + ')').addClass('red');

var iGreenCol = 4;
$('#tbl').find('tr.test > td:nth-of-type(' + iGreenCol + ')').addClass('green');
</script>
```