# iOs 8.x Safari sometimes does not render circle with background-color

Tags: javascript, css, safari, ios8

I am using the newest iOs Safari 8.x. Sometimes the browser does not render some circles with a   background-color. This occurs only in iOs Safari 8.x. All other browsers (including desktop versions) can render those circles perfectly.
The CSS to visualize the circles is generated by using SASS.

I analyzed the problem with Safari Develop, but i didn't found anything useful.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks!

EDIT:

The SASS code to visualize those circles (Custom radio buttons)

```
        .emn-scale-radio {
        @include border-radius(50%);
        width: $psktScaleRadioWidth;
        height: $psktScaleRadioHeight;
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        margin: $psktScaleRadioMarginFull;

        &:last-child {
            margin: $psktScaleRadioMarginLast;
        }

        input[type='radio'],
        [class^="icon-"] {
            display: none;
        }

        @for $i from 0 to length($psktScaleColorCollection) {
            &.emn-scale-radio:nth-child(#{$i+1}) {
                background-color: nth($psktScaleColorCollection, $i+1);
            }

            &.emn-scale-radio-checked:nth-child(#{$i+1}) {
                border: $psktScaleRadioCheckedBorder;
                background-color: $white;

                [class^="icon-"] {
                    color: $mediumBlue01;
                    display: inline-block;
                    position: $psktScaleRadioCheckedIconPosition;
                    right: $psktScaleRadioCheckedIconPositionRight;
                    min-width: $psktScaleRadioCheckedIconMinWidth;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add some code to show us what have you tried so far. We are not magicians ;) (You can take a look to [ask] if you want more info)

Comment: I found this article which shows the same problem. It is currently a bug in iOs 8. --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26032513/ios8-safari-after-a-pushstate-the-nth-child-selectors-not-works