# iOS - insertAfter() not working after append()

Tags: jquery, ios, append, insertafter

I have a dynamically loaded image gallery.  Each image has a numeric data-id, and I want to sort them by ascending numbers.  Then, because there are lots of them, I want to insert a 'back to top' button after every nth image.  The following code works in FF, Chrome and Safari on desktop:

```
$(function() {
    var Arr = $('.card').get();
    var Arr = Arr.sort(function(a,b) {
    var aLoc = +$('.ad',a).data('id'),
     bLoc = +$('.ad',b).data('id')
     return aLoc < bLoc? -1:aLoc > bLoc? 1 :0
     })
    $('#class').append(Arr);  
    $('<div class = "top">TOP</div>').insertAfter('#class div:nth-child(4n)');
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9aoyk8dk/)

Occasionally, though unpredictably as far as I can tell, it also works on iOS, but generally it fails.  I have tried wrapping a setTimeout() function around the insertAfter(), but no difference.

I don't know if it's relevant, but the images are being lazy loaded once the array has been sorted and appended to the main div.

I'd be really grateful for any clues as to where I've gone wrong.

Thanks

EDIT:  This is the lazy load function:

```
$("img.lazy").lazyload({
        threshold : 200
    });
```

It uses the lazyload plugin.  In the working code, the lazy load function appears immediately after `$('#class').append(Arr);`

Comment: Please elaborate what exactly happens on iOS

Comment: Can you show your lazy load function?

Comment: @Tzach The sorted image array is correctly displayed, but the 'top' div is not inserted.

Comment: If you remove the lazyload code, is it working as expected? If you use other method than `insertAfter()`, is it working as expected?

Comment: There would be some error with the `lazyload` call in iOS browser, that stop execution of `insertAfter` code statement

Comment: How are you echoing out the images? Is it in a loop?

Comment: Removing the lazy load function had no effect (other than that the images were not displayed).  The initial array is created by an 'each' function; it is then sorted by the code above.  All that works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might be an iOS8 issue - but changing `:nth-child(n)` to `nth-of-type(n)` seems to have fixed the problem.  Maybe someone with more understanding of iOS might be able to explain what's going on.

See here:[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26032513/ios8-safari-after-a-pushstate-the-nth-child-selectors-not-works)