# :nth-child not working on iosSafari 8

Tags: ios, css, ipad, safari, mobile-safari

I'm using a iPad with ios 8.02 and iosSafari 8.

```
.itemgrid-3cols .item:nth-child(3n+1) {
    clear: left;
}
```

I checked in the browser inspector and above style rule is being applied by iosSafari to every 1st, 3rd, 7th, 8th and 9th `.item`

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 959px) and (min-width: 768px)
   .itemgrid-2cols .item:nth-child(2n+1), .itemgrid-3cols .item:nth-child(2n+1), .itemgrid-4cols .item:nth-child(2n+1), .itemgrid-5cols .item:nth-child(2n+1), .itemgrid-6cols .item:nth-child(2n+1), .itemgrid-7cols .item:nth-child(2n+1) 
   {
       clear: left !important;
   }
}
```

And that style rule is being applied to every `.item` element.  The media query is working properly.

I'm using Telerik AppBuilder to debug the device on Windows, but it you can see this on the device itself.

Here is a [link](http://www.mccabespharmacy.com/special-offers.html) to one of the pages it is occurring.  It only occurs on ios 8.02 with iosSafari 8 as far as I can see.  I checked on browser stack, the chrome emulator and an older iPad 2 with Safari and the error did not occur.

I also checked [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Anth-child) and it says that the `:nth-child` works on iosSafari 8.

Any idea, why this rule is not being applied correctly?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Look at [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Anth-child) again.

In the 'known issues' tab, one of the issues says:

> iOS 8 Safari has [issues with nth-child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26032513/ios8-safari-after-a-pushstate-the-nth-child-selectors-not-works).

### So believe it or not: `nth-child` doesn't work on iOS 8.

The workaround is of course to use `nth-of-type` instead - which *does* work on iOS 8

So (assuming the .item element is a `li`) your code becomes

```
.itemgrid-3cols li:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
    clear: left;
}
```

Comment: Very annoying Apple wouldn't fix these bugs quickly, but thanks for the workaround!