# How to select only the first child of only the second li element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to select the second span from the li element

html

```
<ul>
    <li>
       <span class="item1-class">item 1</span>
       <span class="item2-class">item 2</span>
    </li>
    <li>
       //Can i select this item only without 
       //adding additional class or id
       <span class="item1-class">item 1 needs to be selected</span>              
       <span class="item2-class">item 2</span>
    </li>
    <li>
       <span class="item1-class">item 1</span>
       <span class="item2-class">item 2</span>
    </li>
    <li>
       <span class="item1-class">item 1</span>
       <span class="item2-class">item 2</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

my sass css

```
li {
    .item1-class {
        color:red;
    }
}
```

I can't change the html so I can only use css to select the second item1-class. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean; the obvious answer is to just use `.item2-class {}`, so I'm assuming you mean something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this using the :nth-child/:nth-of-type pseudo selector.

**edit** apparently browser support is now pretty solid, minus IE8. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3

**edit 2** apparently there is an issue with `nth-child` on iOS 8 ( [iOS8 Safari after a pushState the :nth-child() selectors not works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26032513/ios8-safari-after-a-pushstate-the-nth-child-selectors-not-works) ), so `nth-of-type` is the more stable option.

```
 li:nth-of-type(2) .item1-class{
      //your styling here
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are probably looking for something like `:nth-of-type()`.

CSS:

```
li:nth-of-type(2) .item1-class {
    color:red;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hopkins_matt/p11cbL9n/)

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I like @Jesse Kernaghan's answer. Using the [nth-child selector](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/) is what you are looking for.

**SCSS**

```
ul {
    li {
        span {
            &:nth-child(2) {
                color: red;
            } 
        }
    }
}
```