# Bootstrap navbar last-child spacing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, html-lists, navbar

I'm trying to remove the right space for the last element of my navbar.

Bootstrap code :

```
.nav > li > a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}
```

So I tried :

```
.nav > li > a:last-child {
    padding-right: 0 !important;
}
```

It's working but the padding is applied to all elements, not only the last one.

The site is here : http://mrsmith.be

Comment: You want to select the last `li` element, not the last `a` element (which is _every_ `a` element in the menu, because every `a` is the _only_ child of its `li` parent.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, its an alternative solution, which I prefer:

```
ul.nav li:nth-child(5) a {
padding-right: 0 !important;
}
```

The problem you have is, that you try to select the last a element, it should be the last li element.

Hope this helps!

Comment: What happens when a menu item is added or removed through the website's CMS (if it has one)? The CSS would have to be updated also...

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the :last-child selector on the `<li>` instead of the `<a>`. Here's a quick working example, I added a red background so that you can easily see which elements are effected:

```css
.nav > li:last-child > a {
  background: red; 
  padding-right: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul class="nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Using `:last-child` generally has better browser support compared to `:nth-child()`. See [this chart](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selectors/) for specific browser information. [iOS8 also has some notable issues with :nth-child()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26032513/ios8-safari-after-a-pushstate-the-nth-child-selectors-not-works).